# I want to show the number of factors (excluding 1 and itself) of n

Tags: python, for-loop, factors

I want to show n and the number of factors (excluding 1 and itself) of n.
like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhruP.png)

```
n factor
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   0
6   2
7   0
8   2
9   1
10  2
```

So I wrote the code like this
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGaud.png)

```
n = int(input('Enter the number: '))

factor = 0

for a in range(1, n+1):

    if n % a == 0:
        factor += 1
    fctr = factor - 2
        
    print("%d" '\t' "%5d" %(a, fctr))
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. I've been thinking about it for two days, but I still don't get it why it's not working. Did I write "for" incorrectly?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code; paste the code inside the question itself (in a code block).

Comment: It's my first time on this site, so I didn't know I could do this. Thank you for letting me know. I edited it.

Comment: I don't undersatnd your code works? just take the last value of fctr?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing

```
    fctr = factor - 2
```

for every iteration of the loop

```
    for a in range(1, n+1):
```

That would probably give you a negative value in the very beginning.
Since you know you just don't want to count 1 and n why not run the loop as:

```
    for a in range(2, n):
```

Based off of your example, are you trying to print the number of factors of each number from 1 to n? Because that would require another outer for loop. Right now you're only printing the number of factors of n (seen so far at every point of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

If you want number of factors for all the numbers from `1` to `n` you should write two for loops (nested one). One for iterating through numbers from `1` to `n` and the other for finding numbers of factors for `ath` number.

So this solves the problem -

```py
n = int(input('Enter the number: '))

for a in range(1, n+1):
    factor = 0

    for b in range(2, a):

        if a % b == 0:
            factor += 1
        
    print("%d" '\t' "%5d" %(a, factor))
```